# CURRENT_ROLE() behaviour in procedure vs function

Tags: user-defined-functions, roles, procedure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'd like to validate my observation of getting different result from CURRENT_ROLE() when called from a procedure vs UDF..

For Example, from the UI, I create below procedure and function as role_A:

```
create or replace procedure tst_exec_owner_proc()
  returns VARCHAR
  language javascript
  as
  $$
  // Set the second session variable
  var stmt = snowflake.createStatement(
      {sqlText: "select CURRENT_ROLE();"}
      );
  var rs = stmt.execute();  
  rs.next();

  return rs.getColumnValue(1);   
  $$
  ;

create or replace function tst_exec_owner_func()
  returns VARCHAR  
  as
  $$
  select current_role()
  $$;
```

Now, invoking the procedure, and function returns "role_A";
But once I switch to role_B, call tst_exec_owner_proc() returns "role_A" whereas select tst_exec_owner_func() returns "role_B". Is this expected behaviour (assuming role_A and role_B have necessary USAGE grants)?

Answer (score 0):

A stored procedure can execute with the privileges of the owner (an “owner’s rights” stored procedure) or with the privileges of the caller (a “caller’s rights” stored procedure). If you execute the statement CREATE PROCEDURE ... EXECUTE AS CALLER, then in the future the procedure will execute as a caller’s rights procedure. If you execute CREATE PROCEDURE ... EXECUTE AS OWNER, then the procedure will execute as an owner’s rights procedure. By default (if neither OWNER nor CALLER is specified explicitly at the time the procedure is created), the procedure runs as an owner’s rights stored procedure.

Try include EXECUTE AS CALLER in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the response.. Does the UDF not have similar defaults then?

Comment: Yes, Only stored procedure has.